# UnsupportedClassVersionError-AMQPSpout: storm topology not running

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, apache-storm

While trying to submit a storm topology ,

```
./storm jar /home/winoria1/Desktop/stormtopology.jar com.storm.StormTopology
```

I am getting following error-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/rapportive/storm/spout/AMQPSpout : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
at com.winoria.frequest.SuggestionTopology.main(SuggestionTopology.java:28)
```

my java version is

winoria1@winoria:~$ **java -version**

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

winoria1@winoria:~$ **javac -version**

```
javac 1.6.0_27
winoria1@winoria:~$
```

any one help me please.....

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10382929/1113392), see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/1113392)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Major version 51 means that this class was compiled with java 7.
You need to upgrade your java in order to run it.